# Is the set of prime pairs such that $gcd(p-1,q-1) = 2$ of positive density?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Is the set of prime pairs such that $gcd(p-1,q-1) = 2$ of positive density?
For example, for $p,q \leq 10^4$ the answer is approximately $1/2$.

I was wondering if it were possible to use sieve methods and results such as the [Siegel-Walfisz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem) to give a good approximation of prime pairs of this form.

The motivation for the question is for understanding the order of elements in the group $(\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z})^*\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*\times (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*$.

Comment: The question has been answered in Mathoverflow:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253623/is-the-set-of-prime-pairs-such-that-gcdp%E2%88%921-q%E2%88%921-2-of-positive-density